# Implementing ROI pooling in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have written the following code which takes a feature_map tensor of shape `(n_channels, img_height, img_width)` and a region of interest of shape `(5,)` (whose elements are `(1, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)`) and returns the maximum element of each channel over the specified region:

```
def tf_box_pool(self, feature_map, roi):
        ''' Extracts region of interest from feature map
        '''

        # Compute the scaled down region of interest
        self.spatial_scale = K.cast(self.spatial_scale, 'float32')

        roi_start_w = tf.math.scalar_mul(self.spatial_scale, tf.cast(roi[1], 'float32'))
        roi_start_h = tf.math.scalar_mul(self.spatial_scale, tf.cast(roi[2], 'float32'))
        roi_end_w = tf.math.scalar_mul(self.spatial_scale, tf.cast(roi[3], 'float32'))
        roi_end_h = tf.math.scalar_mul(self.spatial_scale, tf.cast(roi[4], 'float32'))

        roi_height = tf.math.round(tf.math.maximum(roi_end_h - roi_start_h + 1, 1))
        roi_width = tf.math.round(tf.math.maximum(roi_end_w - roi_start_w + 1, 1))

        h_start = K.cast(roi_start_h, 'int32')
        height = K.cast(roi_height, 'int32')
        h_end = h_start + height
        w_start = K.cast(roi_start_w, 'int32')
        width = K.cast(roi_width, 'int32')
        w_end = w_start + width     

        mapped_region = feature_map[:, h_start:h_end, w_start:w_end]

        pooled_features = tf.math.reduce_max(mapped_region, axis=[1,2])

        return pooled_features
```

Now, I have two tensors representing a batch of images and a batch of lists of regions of interests, whose shapes are respectively `(batch_size, n_channels, img_width, img_height)` and `(batch_size, n_rois, 5)`.

I want to apply the function above n_rois times to each image in the first tensor, feeding it together with each region of interest in the second tensor. The end result should be a tensor of shape `(batch_size, n_rois, n_channels)`

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you every figure this out?

Comment: @rigo I did and wrote an article about it!
https://medium.com/xplore-ai/implementing-attention-in-tensorflow-keras-using-roi-pooling-992508b6592b